# How to describe a array of integers whose available digits are positive integers

Tags: sql

It is more of a language question as I am working on translating a technical document into English. The current description is as below:

The value of this parameter can be an array of integers or an integer range. The integers start from 0. Examples: '0-2' and '1,2,3'.

My question is: does this description cause confusion to imply that the value must start from 0 which makes the second example look incorrect on first sight?

Comment: Why did you tag this sql? This is more of a general programming question?

Comment: It is part of a sql statement. So I tagged sql

Comment: @RossBush which tag do you suggest? Tag "programming" does not work

Comment: @RossBush Or can you lend a hand to answer my question?

Comment: This doesn't even look like a programming question. https://english.stackexchange.com/ might be a better fit.

Comment: But if the audience is technical enough, "non-negative integers" is how you'd describe the positive integers plus 0. If you use that in the first sentence, you can probably get rid of the second sentence entirely.